# Getting old values from database, even after update?

Tags: mysql, glassfish, sql-update, toplink-essentials

I am using MySQL as DB, and Toplink essential as persistence layer.

There is a column, that I used to update regularly. But am always getting the value the value that was there at instance of START of the server.

But I restart the server, then only, its giving me the updated value.

What could be the problem?

Comment: using two windows; window 1 isn't committed. window 2 doesn't see uncommitted results of window 1?  whereas window 1 can.

Comment: Actually..in all windows its showing result.

Comment: Are you making the updates outside of the application/TopLink? This could cause a caching issue depending on your settings.

Comment: I tried both ways, 1 tried to test things using toplink and other by updating the value manually in DB. Both ways I am getting same result.

Comment: how are you doing the update?  Have you tried an insert or update statement right on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by updating `Persistence.xml`, which allowed to disable any kind of Caching done by toplink.

```
<properties>
    <property name="toplink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
</properties>
```

Refered Link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28221/cfgdepds005.htm#TopLinkCaching